# Disabling double opt-in doesn't seem to work?

Tags: wordpress, mailchimp

So i have a list in Mailchimp. When i go to the settings of this list, under 'List name & default', i have 'double opt-in' disabled.

Now i have this wordpress site that has a button that pops up a form(with plugin called boxzilla). There I have to fill in my name and e-mail, this is with the Mailchimp 4 Wordpress plugin. Then i receive a confirmation e-mail asking me if i want to join this Mailchimp list.

But this seems to me like this is double opt-in? How can i make it so that I only have to fill in the form and that i joined the Mailchimp list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is a problem with the plugin you use, even if you disable double opt-in on Mailchimp, you still can send the option through the API (the way the plugin connects to Mailchimp).

Anyways, check the "Settings" section of your form and disable "Double opt-in" there.[image]
I hope it helps.

Comment: You are correct sir, thanks! Enjoy your bounty, don't spend it all at once though!